# DevExpress Grid Control runtime binding to database with autoupdate

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net, devexpress, npgsql

I have WinForms application, where I use DevExpress GridControl to view data from database (postgresql 9.4 throught npgsql 3.0.5 provider). I don't know why I can't create binding using VisualStudio integrating components, so one possible way to create binding is to do in at runtime. I use code close to code in this manual: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2240.

I wonder to make the view auto update if something was changed in database for example if there were any updates, but I don't know how to do this. At least I need a mechanism which makes me possible to get notification if the content of database were changed, but yet again I don't know how to implement with with npgsql provider. May be I need to install some adapters or something like this. I found SQlDependency class provided under ADO.Net, but as I see it is only for SQL Server. I think I need something similar.

Comment: You should probably look into PostgreSQL asynchronous notifications and update triggers which would fire them. Npgsql has a ContinuousProcessing mode that allows you to receive those notifications (although the API will probably change significantly in 3.1, the next major version).